# [Spring][MongoDB] @Unwrapped annotation always returns null on find operations

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I've been taking a look at the annotation `@Unwrapped` from Spring Data MongoDb library but I can't make it fully work on my Kotlin project. I've been through the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/main/src/main/asciidoc/reference/unwrapping-entities.adoc) and although the writing operations work as intended, when doing a find by id to return the entity the wrapped object is always null.
I've been trying to investigate why this may be for two days now with no avail. Hope someone from the audience can give me an hint, I'd be much appreciated.

This is the code:

```
data class UserName(
    val firstname: String? = null,
    val lastname: String? = null
)

@Document(collection = "accounts")
data class AccountEntity(
    @Id
    val id: String,

    @Unwrapped(onEmpty = OnEmpty.USE_NULL)
    val username: UserName? = null
}
```

When I try to save an instance of `AccountEntity(id=123,username=Username("John","Doe")` the document is saved and returned correctly.
The document in Mongo:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(123),
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe"
}
```

However, when trying to read the same object (say, in a method like findById(id=123)) the wrapped object is always null (`AccountEntity(id=123,username=null`). I've tried to add `Document` and `Field` annotations on the Username as well as other variations here and there but with no different results. I'm out of options at the moment.

I'm using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.7.10.jar (planning to go to version 3 really soon) and org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb-3.4.10.